# why does changing from ' to " affect the behavior of this one-liner?

Tags: perl, shell, double-quotes, single-quotes

Why is it that simply changing from enclosing my one-liner with `'` instead of `"` affects the behavior of the code? The first line of code produces what is expected and the second line of code gives (to me!) an unexpected result, printing out an unexpected array reference.

```
$ echo "puke|1|2|3|puke2" | perl -lne 'chomp;@a=split(/\|/,$_);print $a[4];'
puke2
$ echo "puke|1|2|3|puke2" | perl -lne "chomp;@a=split(/\|/,$_);print $a[4];"
```

This is the Perl version:

```
$ perl -v

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

ARRAY(0x1f79b98)
```

Comment: Try: echo "chomp;@a=split(/\|/,$_);print $a[4];", no Perl involved, and you'll see what you are passing to Perl in the second case.

Comment: @martinclayton  Nice. One thing -- the pipe in the question affects `$_` so that part won't be accurate.  (While data may not be piped at all in the actual problem, of course.)

Comment: @martinclayton Repeatedly executing this is entertaining :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With double quotes you are letting the shell interpolate variables first.

As you can check, `$_` and `$a` are unset in the subshell forked for pipe by the parent shell. See a comment on `$_` below.

So the double-quoted version is effectively

```
echo "puke|1|2|3|puke2" | perl -lne 'chomp;@a=split(/\|/);print [4];'
```

what prints the arrayref `[4]`.

---

A comment on the effects of having `$_` exposed to Bash.  Thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for bringing this up.

The `$_` is one of a handful of [special shell parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0024_005f) in Bash. It contains the last argument of the previous command, or the pathname of what invoked the shell or commands (via `_` environment variable).  See the link for a full description.

However, here it is being interpreted in a subshell forked to run the `perl` command, its first. Apparently it is not even set, as seen with

```
echo hi;  echo hi | echo $_
```

which prints an empty line (after first `hi`). The reason may be that the `_` environment variable just isn't set for a subshell for a pipe, but I don't see why this would be the case.  For example,

```
echo hi; (echo $_)
```

prints two lines with `hi` even though `( )` starts a subshell.

In any case, `$_` in the given pipeline isn't set.

The `split` part is then `split(/\|/)`, so via default `split(/\|/, $_)` -- with nothing to split.  With `-w` added this indeed prints a warning for use of uninitialized `$_`.

Note that this behavior depends on the shell. The `tcsh` won't run this with double quotes at all. In `ksh` and `zsh` the last part of pipeline runs in the main shell, not a subshell, so `$_` is there.

Comment: Actually, `$_` in many shells is the last argument of the most recent command, but if it were unassigned, the Perl code would look like `split(/\|/,)` which defaults to `split(/\|/, $_)` anyway. The real problem, as you say, is that `$a[4]` is reduced to `[4]`.

Comment: @Borodin  I think that it ends up empty because of the pipe.  (It did in my brief tests.)  However, I should and will explain it better, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is actual a shell topic, not a perl topic.

In shell:

Single quotes preserve the literal value of all of the characters they contain, including the $ and backslash. However, with double quotes, the $, backtick, and backslash characters have special meaning.

For example:

`'\"'` evaluates to `\"`

whereas

`"\'"` evaluates to just `'`

because with double quotes, the backslash gets a special meaning as the escape character.